# Xcode. UITextField custom keyboard : arrow buttons

Tags: xcode, cursor, uitextfield, move

Need your help a little.
I have made a custom keyboard and added it to my UITextFields.inputView . Everything works well. But i met some problems with making the buttons for moving the cursor in the field left and right. Actually, i made them and they work. But, the TextField itself doesnt properly show the changes of cursor position. 
If the text gets out of range of the field, and i move the cursor out of the range of the field, the field itself doesnt refresh. I mean the cursor goes exactly as it has to, but it gets out of the visible area of the field. 
So the question is, how to make the UITextField refresh?

posting my code for button, which moves the cursor in the left:
(works like selecting text in x position with 0 length)

// object - is my UITextField
//pos - position of the cursor

```
-(IBAction)moveLeft:(UIButton*)sender{
UITextRange *selectedRange = [object selectedTextRange];
int pos = [object offsetFromPosition:object.endOfDocument toPosition:selectedRange.start];
if ([object.text length]+pos>0){
        NSRange range= NSMakeRange([object.text length]+pos-1, 0);

        UITextPosition *start = [object positionFromPosition:[object beginningOfDocument]
                                                      offset:range.location];
        UITextPosition *end = [object positionFromPosition:start
                                                    offset:range.length];
        [object setSelectedTextRange:[object textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end]];
        **[self updateTextField];**
    }    
}
```

how to make this "updateTextField" method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did this recently when using PKCustomKeyboard.

```
- (IBAction)leftArrowPressed:(id)sender
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
    UITextRange *selectedRange = [(UITextField *)self.textView selectedTextRange];
    UITextPosition *startPosition = [(UITextField *)self.textView positionFromPosition :[(UITextField *)self.textView beginningOfDocument] offset : 0];

    if (![(UITextField *)self.textView offsetFromPosition : selectedRange.start toPosition : startPosition] == 0)
    {
        // Calculate the new position, - for left and + for right
        UITextPosition *newPosition = [(UITextField *)self.textView positionFromPosition : selectedRange.start offset : -1];

        // Construct a new range using the object that adopts the UITextInput, our textfield
        UITextRange *newRange = [(UITextField *)self.textView textRangeFromPosition : newPosition toPosition : newPosition];

        // Set new range
        [(UITextField *)self.textView setSelectedTextRange : newRange];
    }
}
```

You need to have a reference to the UIInputView's TextView. (PKCustomKeyboard does this)

```
@property (strong) id<UITextInput> textView;
```